# Dask map becomes sequential after foldby

Tags: dask

I've been using dask to do custom ETL jobs with jupyter (works like a charm).

Most of my pipelines are just `filter` -> `map` -> `foldby` -> `map`, and I've found that the second `map` operation (after the `folby`) is executing sequentially (see the bokeh plot below).

Code snippet:

```py
(
    db
    .read_text(path, storage_options=credentials)
    .filter(predicate)
    .map(transform)
    .foldby(key, binop, initial, combine, initial)
    .map(transform2)
)
```

[image: dask-profiler-bokeh-plot]

Is this normal? I don't see why the `.map(transform2)` operation needs to be executed sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of foldby is a bag with a single partition.  You might consider `repartition`ing your bag after the foldby to split it up again.

Comment: Awesome. `repartition` ended up being quite slow. I ended up making the `foldby` operation come last and now it's blazing fast :) THANKS!

Comment: Still, looks like the foldby operation has a huge task being executed sequentially at the end. Is this normal?

Comment: It looks like foldby aggregates all of the intermediate results into a single output before processing.  This could be improved if the user were asked to also provide a combination function.  You might want to raise an issue.